# How to fix ' type error cannot read property 0 of undefined '?

Tags: node.js, express

I can't get `row[].column_name` in my .hbs file althougth when I `console.log(row)` it shows the result.

The error is the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 0 of undefined

```
router.get('/:id/baiviet', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var p = baivietModel.allByCat(id);
  var q = chuyenmuc.singel(id); // singel(id) return a promise
  var row;

  q.then(rows => {
    row = rows;
  });

  p.then(rows => {
    for (const cm of res.locals.lcChuyenmuc) {
      if (cm.ID == +id) {
        cm.isActive = true;
      }
    }
    res.render('vwBaiviet/byCat', {
      baiviet: rows,
      CM: row[0]
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

My .hbs file:

```
{{this.CM.Name}}
```

Comment: As i see it, it seems that the 2nd promise block, is executed, before the 1st promise block update the `row` variable. So when it comes on the line to use `CM: row[0]` , `row` array is undefined.

Comment: Thank u. So how I get row[0] to CM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 0 of undefined

```
  var row;
```

Will initialize the `row` value to be `undefined` hence you're getting that error.

If you use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you can resolve two promises and send a value at once.

```
router.get('/:id/baiviet', (req, res) => {
  var {id} = req.params;

  Promise.all([
    baivietModel.allByCat(id),
    chuyenmuc.singel(id) // singel(id) return a promise
  ]).then(([prows, qrows]) => {

    // ... your other code

    res.render('vwBaiviet/byCat', {
      baiviet: prows,
      CM: qrows[0]
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

});
```